# query choices with forms.ModelChoiceField that doesn't show object1

Tags: python, django

I am  building a web site in Django that has two apps and models -- maxes and workouts. I want the maxes form to be able to query the workouts model in order to get Lifts.

I can get it to work by adding in:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '%s' % (self.lift)
```

workouts/models.py

````py
from django.db import models
from utils.models import (CreationModificationDateMixin)
# Create your models here.

class wplans(CreationModificationDateMixin):
    wplan   = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    wnumber = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    lift    = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    weight  = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    sets    = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    reps    = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.lift)
```python 

maxes/forms.py
```python
class maxesModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    lift = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        label=("Lift"),
        queryset=wplans.objects.all(),
        required=True
    )
````

It works but I want to be able to add in the wplan field into a form, but it still show lift name now the wplan. If I take out the `def __str__` it shows wplanobject(1)

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, you want to alter the representation of the objects? The user still selects `wplans`, but you want to present these as `lift`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the label by *subclassing* the [**`ModelChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield), and override the [**`label_from_instance(..)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.to_field_name):

```
# app/fields.py

from django.forms.models import ModelChoiceField

class WpanModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return str(obj.lift)
```

In your `MaxesModelForm`, you can then use:

```
# app/forms.py

# ...

from app.fields import WpanModelChoiceField

class maxesModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    lift = WpanModelChoiceField(
        label=("Lift"),
        queryset=wplans.objects.all(),
        required=True
    )
```

We can also patch a `ModelChoiceField` directly, like:

```
# app/forms.py

# ...

class maxesModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    lift = ModelChoiceField(
        label=("Lift"),
        queryset=wplans.objects.all(),
        required=True
    )
    lift.label_from_instance = lambda obj: str(obj.lift)
```

Comment: The subclassing worked! And that is a really slick way to work with forms. Thanks for your help